# With Nest camera, is there a way to completely disable event generation for a zone?

Tags: nest-cam

Is there a way to make a given area of the camera view generate no events, not even those that show up in the timeline?

I have set up zones for the areas of interest to me, but I continue to get events for areas outside any zone. I can set up a zone for areas that are uninteresting, but events are still processed and shown.

[image: nest uninteresting events]